# Callback after line chart rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I implement charts 2 libraries in my project. it's working well. I want to show an alert message after the line chart rendered completely.
is there any callback function or anything else?
how can I show a message after the line chart displayed?

**I want to do like before chart render showing loader at the end displayed chart I want to hide that loader.**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use **[`onComplete`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html)** callback function of animation. This will be called after the chart (animation) is completely rendered.

```
options: {
   animation: {
      onComplete: function() {
         alert('Line Chart Rendered Completely!');
      }
   },
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank You :) that i want :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to run your logic only for one time after render,

```
options: {
   animation: {
      onComplete: function(chart) {
      if(chart.initial){
         alert('do something here only for one time after render');
      }

      }
   },
   ...
}
```